# invalid size of struct after realloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc, sizeof, realloc

I want to load records from a file into a dynamic array. I have the following code:

```
typedef struct my_data {
    char name[100];
}my_data;
struct my_data *data;

void load_data()
{
struct my_data *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    FILE * in;
    if((in = fopen("data.txt","rt")) != NULL) {
    temp = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(my_data));
    while(!feof(in))
        {
            fscanf(in,"%s", &temp[i].name);
            i++;
            temp = realloc(temp,((i+1)*sizeof(my_data)));
        };
        fclose(in);
    data = temp;
    free(temp);

    for (i=0;i<sizeof(data);i++ )
        printf("%s\n",data[i].name);
    }
```

I have over 100 records. Why does it show only 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sizeof(data)
```

Above gives the size of `data` which is of type `my_data *`, 4 bytes on your system. To get the number of records, follow the same logic as how you allocated the memory (i.e., `i+1` records). Note that you have reassigned `i` to **0** in the for loop initialization expression.

Comment: I see, you're right. But is there any other way to export the number of records except than making int i global ?

Comment: @SamReina You can always pass the size together with the pointer. Or you can put the pointer and the size in a struct.

Comment: thanks for the notification, but that loop is for testing purposes only. so shall I add to the structure the total value of int (outside the loop) or each value(inside the loop) and for the last case, how do I calculate the total? I mean if for each array [i] the corresponding value of int is i I don't get it how I can calculate the total. Or shall I get int i from last element which will be the total? sorry for so many questions but I'm still trying to learn

Answer (score 0):

Because data is just a pointer to a `struct my_data`. It's equal to `sizeof(struct my_data *)` which is equal to `sizeof(void *)` and returns the size of a pointer (depending on your system, this is 4 or 8 or something else).

You cannot use `sizeof` to get the length of an array in C. You'll need to save the length in a variable of your own.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(my_data) equals 4 because actually the struct only holds a pointer to char. Not a string of 100 chars.